# Make an array of methods to call

Tags: android

I have some classes on my code and based on the click of the `listview` i want to run the selected class. What I mean is that if a user clicks on position 0 I want to run method `GoToTown()`.
I have more than 40 methods so if I do it with `if / elseif` it would be really bad. I have a custom adapter for the `listview` so probably I could use it somehow?

Is there some way I could pass an array to do it?

Comment: You should include some code in your question to demonstrate what you want to do

Comment: What do you mean? 40 classes or methods?

Comment: I'm sorry you are right Methods. (I'm just kind of new in development)

Comment: I think this is the answer that I was looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280727/java-creating-an-array-of-methods

Comment: @marduc812 yes, you can also check this pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 40 different methods, use only 1 (the one which should get the listview result and call one of the 40 methods). And then you should have a [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) inside it:

```
// "number" is the number if the item clicked in the list
switch (number) {
case 0: // First item was clicked, counting starts from 0
    // Put some code here
    break;
case 1: // Second item...
    // Other code
    break;
// Etc.
default: // You did not define a "case" for a number, default gets executed
    // Code here
}
```